# SQL to reset a number of colums to default

Tags: oracle, sql-update

I want to write a SQL that resets all colums in a table back to default, except a couple of colums like the primary key.

I just want to name the colums NOT to update, and reset everything else. There are quite many colums in the table, and I dont whant to write:

```
update my_table set column1 = DEFAULT, column2 = DEFAULT,  ... where  ...
```

for all colums, since there are quite many.

Any ideas? I am using Oracle

Comment: you can use dbms_redefinition using the intermedietery table with default value to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a procedure to do what you want, but if your only problem is the heavy burden of writing the SQL, you can automate that with ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view. You can improve the idea for your needs:

```
select 
    'update ' || TABLE_NAME ||
  'set ' ||
    COLUMN_NAME || ' = DEFAULT'
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
where 
    table_name = <YOUR_TABLE>
```